# Crystal report pro 11 crashes when linking tables

Tags: crystal-reports, odbc, crystal-reports-xi

I have a series problem with Crystal report pro version 11.5.11.1470 SP 5. When i make a new report and add multiple tables and just press on link tab to make links between tables, it crashes and closes. I uninstalled the program so many times and installed it again but in vain. I googled this issue the whole day but with no luck at all. the technical issue log showes the following:

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: crw32.exe
  Application Version:  11.5.11.1470
  Application Timestamp:    492e9155
  Fault Module Name:    MFC71U.DLL
  Fault Module Version: 7.10.3077.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   3e77fc29
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00032e72
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 1fc1
  Additional Information 2: 1fc163a1c57ae45571bce37d539b233f
  Additional Information 3: 12a3
  Additional Information 4: 12a3f41f6385dcf1330ec81c9df2618c
```

Comment: A quick search turned up MFCU71U.DLL as a component of Visual Studio, is that installed too (maybe an older version with an older DLL)?

Comment: @EvilBob22 Thanks for your reply. But i didn't install visual studio on my pc.

Comment: Then it is probably either your Crystal source installation or the ODBC.  Can you successfully test the data source from Control Panel -> Advanced Settings -> Data sources (ODBC)?

Comment: @EvilBob22 i uninstalled the application so many times and reinstalled it again but this didn't make any difference. Regarding my ODBC i am pretty sure that it's configured correctly.

Comment: That was why I was thinking it might be the installer itself.  What kind of ODBC is it?  It might be the ODBC driver for that type, and even if that is fine, some of them (notably MS SQL) have a "Test Connection" option.  If that doesn't work, there is something that needs tweaking there.

Comment: My ODBC is for iSeries ODBC Access Driver (IBM)

Comment: I don't know that one.  Can you re-install the ODBC driver?